# Pandas Dataframe Reshape/Pivot - Duplicate Values in Index Error

Tags: pandas, pivot

I'm using Python 2.7 with Pandas 0.19.2

I've looked at some similar questions/answers to this problem but still haven't been able to solve.

I have the following dataframe:

```
          Date         name      objects
0   2005-11-17         Pete        6
1   2014-02-04         Rob         3
2   2012-02-13         Rob         2
3   2004-12-16         Julia       4
4   2012-02-13         Mike        9
```

I want to reshape it as follows:

```
              Pete   Rob    Julia   Mike

2005-11-17     6     Nan     Nan    Nan
2014-02-04    Nan     3      Nan    Nan
2012-02-13    Nan     2      Nan    9
2004-12-16    Nan    Nan      4     Nan
```

I have been trying to run `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='name', value='objects')` but I get an `'index has duplicate value'` error.

I thought that `pivot` or `pivot_table` work in these situations since there is essentially no 'conflict' between indexes and columns (e.g. multiple values for 'Rob' and '2014-02-04' in the dataframe).

I am not looking to aggregate - just reshape.  Also in the example the dates are not in order - but that doesn't matter.

I feel this should be an easy fix but I can't see it.  Can someone share some insight?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in your real data are duplicates, see sample:

```
print (df)
         Date   name  objects
0  2005-11-17   Pete        6
1  2014-02-04    Rob        3
2  2012-02-13    Rob        2
3  2004-12-16  Julia        4
4  2012-02-13   Mike        9 <-duplicates for 2012-02-13 and Mike
5  2012-02-13   Mike       18 <-duplicates for 2012-02-13 and Mike
```

Solution are [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function, default is `np.mean` but can be changed to `sum`, 'meadian', `first`, `last`.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='name', values='objects', aggfunc=np.mean)
print (df)
name        Julia  Mike  Pete  Rob
Date                              
2004-12-16    4.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
2005-11-17    NaN   NaN   6.0  NaN
2012-02-13    NaN  13.5   NaN  2.0 <-13.5 is mean
2014-02-04    NaN   NaN   NaN  3.0
```

Another solution with `groupby`, aggregate function and `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date','name'])['objects'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
name        Julia  Mike  Pete  Rob
Date                              
2004-12-16    4.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
2005-11-17    NaN   NaN   6.0  NaN
2012-02-13    NaN  13.5   NaN  2.0
2014-02-04    NaN   NaN   NaN  3.0
```

For checking duplicated is possible use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Date','name'], keep=False)]
print (df)
         Date  name  objects
4  2012-02-13  Mike        9
5  2012-02-13  Mike       18
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I will check my data for the duplicates as you suggest.  Is there a general rule when to use pivot vs. pivot_table?  I also gather that your two solutions (pivot_table and groupby) won't work if in fact I do have a duplicate like you suggest?

Comment: Hmmm, if not duplicates use `pivot`, if duplicates `pivot_table` or `groupby`+ `unstack`. It is general rule.

Comment: I add code for check duplicates, please check last edit.

Comment: Thanks.  Will check.  `pivot_table` and `groupby + unstack` work if duplicates?  to then aggregate the values where there are duplicates?

Comment: yes, exactly. it aggregate only duplicates as you can see in sample - `13.5` value is mean with `(9+18)/2`

Comment: And if in data is only one duplicate, `pivot` function fails.

Comment: Indeed I do have a few duplicates in my real data. I actually had tried `pivot_table` but had not included an aggfunction (thought default was sum) so I got an error there too.  Thought I was close. It's always the last 2% of something that takes the longest!!

Comment: @Windstorm1981 I'm just validating jezrael's answer and comments. You can use set_index in conjunction with unstack or... pivot in the case where you do **not** have duplicates. However, groupby with sum and pivot_table with an aggregation function like sum were intended to handle this exact scenario. Jezrael's answer is the perfect answer for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.pivot()`:

```
In [205]: x.pivot(index='Date', columns='name', values='objects')
Out[205]:
name        Julia  Mike  Pete  Rob
Date
2004-12-16    4.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
2005-11-17    NaN   NaN   6.0  NaN
2012-02-13    NaN   9.0   NaN  2.0
2014-02-04    NaN   NaN   NaN  3.0
```

alternative solution:

```
In [207]: x.groupby(['Date','name'])['objects'].first().unstack('name')
Out[207]:
name        Julia  Mike  Pete  Rob
Date
2004-12-16    4.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
2005-11-17    NaN   NaN   6.0  NaN
2012-02-13    NaN   9.0   NaN  2.0
2014-02-04    NaN   NaN   NaN  3.0
```

Actually `pivot_table()` - does something very similar to mentioned solution

PS tested using Pandas version 0.19.2